# Pandas Conditional Drop

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm trying to conditionally drop rows out of a pandas dataframe, using syntax as such:

```
if ((df['Column_1'] == 'value_1') & (df['Column_2'] == 'value_2')):
    df['Columns_3'] == df['Column_4']
else:
    df.drop()
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
df = df.drop(df[(df['Column1'] != 'value_1') & (df['Colum2'] != 'value_2')].index)
df['Column3'] = df['Column4']
```

Comment: This looks right, but can it be expanded across multiple conditions? Say in my post after the if statement and before drop, you have: `elif ((df['Column_1'] == 'value_1') & (df['Column_2'].isin(['value_3', 'value_4', 'value_5']))).all():   df['Column_3'] == df['Column_5']`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[(df['Column_1'] == 'value_1') & (df['Column_2'] == 'value_2'),'Column3'] = df.loc[(df['Column_1'] == 'value_1') & (df['Column_2'] == 'value_2'),'Column4']

df = df[df['Column3]==df['Column4']
```

When working with Pandas, best to get into the practice of trying to use some of the built-in C loop functionality.

There would also be a way of updating Column 3 based on the above condition. I'd need a data set to play around with though. Something like...

```
df['Column3'].update(the_condition)
```

update requires that the indices line up

could also look into transform and apply

```
df['Column3'].transform(the_condition)
```

or:

```
df['Column3'].apply(the_condition)
```